# Underscores prepended when display: inline-block is used

Tags: css

This seems to be occurring when I add `display: inline-block` to my anchors. Does anyone know why this is and how I can solve it?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
.nav{
  background-color: $light-grey;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 10px solid $yellow;
  border-bottom: 10px solid $yellow;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.nav li{
  display: inline;
}

.nav a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 5% 30px 0;
  color: $dark-blue;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: thats not an underscore that is a border-bottom I bet... use firebug in FF to see all the css styles affecting tha a

Comment: yeah, that makes more sense for it to be a border-bottom issue. Thanks for the tip. I'll just start turning stuff on and off until I isolate it.

Comment: No just use firebug in firefox - it will help you isolate it quicker

Comment: Or similar DOM viewer in the browser of your choice (but Firebug is defacto standard ;)

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it:

```
u{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks for putting me on the right path, Paul.

Comment: ahha :) No problem and see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pT_pDe54aA for firebug tute. You can also turn styles on and off in firebug ;)

Comment: How annoying! I had the same problem and couldn't find this "underscore", didn't think about it being an anchor tag which is underlined by default. I'll never get that 10 minutes back!